# I am using Emgu.CV.monotouch which is giving an error in my project

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

How to add `Monotouch.AVFoundation` Framework linking in Xamarin.ios project? Please can anyone tell me in detail? I need this because I am using `Emgu.CV.Monotouch.dll` which is giving errors as

> MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium. Please       verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are    properly linked in.
>
> Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class:   _OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor. If '_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor' is a protocol from a third-party binding, please check that it has the [Protocol] attribute in its api definition file, otherwise verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in. (MT5211)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the binding (the assembly) is out of date with the latest Xamarin.iOS version.

The **new registrars** available in [7.2.1](http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_7/xamarin.ios_7.2/#1) (and later) requires a bit more information (like the `[Protocol]` attributes) in order to work correctly (and solve a lot of small issues). Details on how to update the bindings are part of the links in the release notes (see earlier link).

It is possible to *workaround* this by (without fixing the bindings) using the `--registrar:legacy` option. That will effectively use the **old** registrars (and you won't get the benefits from the new ones). Again this is described in the release notes.